# Use language override to create custom title tags for URL's

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, seo

I have this piece of code that already runs on the pages I need this done. (The entire Joomla 3.9 site is a Frankenstein of custom code, components, etc. )

```
   $placeholder_country = JText::_('COM_ACME_PLACEHOLDER_COUNTRY_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$var['country'])));
    if($placeholder_country === 'COM_ACME_PLACEHOLDER_COUNTRY_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$var['country'])) || !$placeholder_country) $placeholder_country = '';

    $article->text = JString::str_ireplace("{%placeholder_country%}", $placeholder_country, $article->text);
```

I tried adding the following to see if I can get this to set the title the same way.

```
     $placeholder_country = JText::_('titlenick_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$var['country'])));
    if($placeholder_country === 'titlenick_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$var['country'])) || !$placeholder_country) $placeholder_country = '';

    $document->setTitle = JString::str_ireplace("{%placeholder_country%}", $placeholder_country, $article->text);
```

Meaning, I go into the Joomla Language overrides section, add the Language Constant, for example, "TITLENICK_PERU"

In the "text" Id enter the page title I want. "Cheap Peru vacations" for example.

Comment: You might find the 'alt' option of the TEXT API, https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Language.Text.html, helpful. I am not really clear what it is you are trying to achieve to be more specific but the alt option is quite handy once you understand how it works.

Comment: Not sure thats what I need. I basically need a way to enter custom titles for URLs that are created by a custom component. Im trying to see if its possible to customize the top peice of code I posted to fit my request.